# D3 circle issue

Tags: d3.js

I have a problem in D3.
When i try to insert first circle it will insert only one, but When I insert the second circle, the previous one is again inserted automatically.

**Video link:**
https://vimeo.com/750234583

**Image**
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/32470753?key=a5a4e1f60b1e2f4a3afe77571daad283

**Code** https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-fast-eowul6?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem.

[Here is example link](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-fast-eowul6?file=/index.js)